# 1 GeV Proton beam scattering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

If a problem gives only this information, should it be understood as kinetics or as total energy?

As the rest mass equivalent energy of the proton is 938.28 MeV, it would only be available 61.72 MeV as kinetics energy. Is it sufficient for 208 Pb scatering?

Comment: One normally does not include rest energy when quoting proton beam energies.

Comment: @LewisMiller thanks! Is there a reason for that? Is it because of the kinetic energy conservation?

Comment: I think its just convention.  In the early days when all beam energies were low it didn't make sense to add in the rest energy.

Comment: Not responsive to the questions, but the Geiger and Marsden conducted their famous scattering experiment on gold (attributed to Rutherford) using $5.3\,\mathrm{MeV}$ alphas from a radioactive source. You don't need a lot of energy to do scattering, though you can need quite a lot of energy to learn particular things in the process.

Comment: @dmckee to obtain, for example the graphic of the intensity of scattered beams in terms of the scattering angle? Is there a way I can connect the first minimum with the kinectic energy or something like that? thanks in advance

Comment: @AAAAAA You can conduct that experiment at any beam energy. What information will be contained in the results depends on the energy. Like I said, the 'Rutherford' scattering experiment was conducted at a only five MeV and they learned that there is a small heavy core to a atom. But if you want to measure the charge radius of lead-208 you're going to need more energy than that (say a couple hundred MeV at a minimum). No one can tell you how much energy is enough without knowing what your question is.